# How to linearize this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE system 
$$
x'=-x+xy.\qquad y'=y+x^2.
$$
It has equilibrium $(0,0)$.

What's the linearization in $(0,0)$? The linearization of the second equation is just $y'=y$. But what's the linearization of the first one? Or is this already linear?

Is the linearization matrix just
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}y-1 & 0\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite, the system is not linear since it contains non-linear terms such as $x^2$. Also,

$$A =\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial x'}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial y'}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}y-1 & x\\2x & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Evaluating at $(0,0)$ gives
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thats the Jacobimatrix.

Comment: Which is how you linearize the system.